# Quotable Literature for the Enthalpy of a Proton

Tags: physical-chemistry, computational-chemistry, enthalpy, reference-request, protons

A proton obviously has no electronic energy, no vibrational and no rotational degrees of freedom. Therefore I think it is fair to assume, that $$H(\ce{H+})=\frac32\cdot \mathcal{R}\cdot T$$ holds for the translational degrees of freedom. I am looking for some quotable literature where they state that, or if that has not been stated anywhere, how to derive this.

I am doing quantum chemical calculations, i.e. gas phase. I define the [proton affinities](http://goldbook.iupac.org/P04907.html) via 
$$\text{PA}(\ce{M})=-\left(H(\ce{H+M})-\bigr[H(\ce{M})+H(\ce{H+})\bigr]\right)$$
for the reaction
 $$\ce{H+ + M -> H+M}.$$ 
This is respecting the (quite common) sign convention to show the energy released upon binding a proton. 
I need a reliable source or at least a best-practice example(s) for $H(\ce{H+})$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quite complete procedure in the calculation of proton affinities from *ab initio* calculations is referenced in an article by [H. Audier et al., *Int. J. Mass Spectrom.* 1996](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0168-1176%2896%2904397-2). It goes much further in the procedure than only on the calculation of the enthalpy of a proton (including corrections due to the basis set superposition error and so on), but confirms that you are right in assuming that the enthalpy of a proton is $3/2 RT$.

Comment: Unfortunately they also only state my suspicion as a fact (no proof) - but at least now I know that I am not the only one thinking so... (sorry for the delay in accepting the answer).